# c# currency combobox

Tags: c#

I wanted to make a Currency ComboBox (drop down list) control for my application and given the currencies exist as properties inside the RegionInfo object I wandered if anyone had a neat way of putting them into an array.

Cheers,

Richard

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this:

```
CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures)
           .Select(c => new RegionInfo(c.LCID).CurrencySymbol)
           .Distinct()
```

On my (Windows 7) machine, this produces

```
ر.س.‏
лв.
€
NT$
Kč
kr.
$
₪
Ft
¥
₩
kr
zł
R$
fr.
lei
р.
kn
Lek
฿
TL
Rs
Rp
₴
Ls
Lt
т.р.
ريال
₫
դր.
man.
ден.
R
Lari
रु
RM
Т
сом
S
m.
so'm
টা
ਰੁ
રૂ
ଟ
ரூ
రూ
ರೂ
ക
ট
₮
£
៛
₭
ل.س.‏
රු.
ETB
؋
PhP
ރ.
N
$b
һ.
с.
Q
RWF
XOF
د.ع.‏
Fr.
Din.
ман.
сўм
৳
DZD
ج.م.‏
HK$
Дин.
S/.
د.ل.‏
KM
د.ج.‏
MOP
CHF
₡
د.م.‏
B/.
د.ت.‏
RD$
КМ
ر.ع.‏
J$
Bs. F.
ر.ي.‏
BZ$
د.ا.‏
TT$
ل.ل.‏
Z$
د.ك.‏
Php
د.إ.‏
$U
د.ب.‏
Gs
ر.ق.‏
Rs.
L.
C$
```

Answer (score 0):

For those of us on  .NET 2 (with no Select inside arrays) and to break out some of the stuff happening in SLak's excellent answer:

(Now using GetDistinctValues from http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2008/05/15/getting-distinct-values-from-arrays.aspx because there is no Distinct  in .Net 3.5)

```
        CultureInfo[] cultures = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures);
        List<string> CountryCodes = new List<string>();
        foreach (CultureInfo ci in cultures)
        {
            RegionInfo ri = new RegionInfo(ci.LCID);
            CountryCodes.Add(ri.ISOCurrencySymbol);
        }
        string [] CountryCodeArray = GetDistinctValues(CountryCodes.ToArray());

public string[] GetDistinctValues(string[] array)
{
    List<string> list = new List<string>();

    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        if (list.Contains(array[i]))
            continue;
        list.Add(array[i]);
    }
    return list.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: You can call `Array.ConvertAll`.  Also, `Distinct` is new to .Net 3.5.